# Thread and queue function in python

Tags: python, multithreading, terminal, queue

I'm new in python and thread ,i start learning by create this code:

```
def PutChar(Ch):     #ask user to put the correct char

    b=raw_input("Enter "+Ch+" char ")
    while (b != Ch):
         b=raw_input("Enter "+Ch+" char ")
    return b     

def sleep_time():#sleep time function

    n=11
    print(t)
    if(t=='f'):
        n=10000
        print(t)
    for i in range(1,n):
        time.sleep(1)
        if(i==5):
            print"\ntime almost finish:",i
            print"Enter f char "

    print"\ntime finish",i

def Return():"""function return to test the return value of thread"""

    t=q.get()
    return t

def PutFchar(in_q):   #function for putting the F char
        k=PutChar('f')
        #putEchar()
        in_q.put(k)

def PutEchar():#function for putting the E char
    PutChar('e')
    print("cycle correct")
```

and i have this code in main() function:

```
q=Queue.Queue()
t2=threading.Thread(target=sleep_time)
t1=threading.Thread(target=PutFchar, args=(q,))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
print"Program finish"
```

i have three questions:

First: why when i use the queue function the code block ? i mean in this code i use thread for running the `PutFchar()` and `sleep_time()` functions in parallel but when i add the queue function for share data between threads functions the `PutFchar` work but the `sleep_time` function block 
this is the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs5UU.png)

Second: i call the `PutEchar()` in the `PutFchar()` function but the console show me an error so what i can do for calling function in thread function ?
this is the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByeSM.png)

finally: i put a `Return()` function to test the return value of `queue` in first time i put in Return() function the `q.get()` directly like this:

```
def Return():
  return q.get()
```

and print it to show the values:

```
def sleep_time():
    n=11
    print(q.get())
    if(q.get()=='f'):
        n=10000
        print(n)
    for i in range(1,n):
        time.sleep(1)
        if(i==5):
            print"\ntime almost finish:",i
            print"Enter f char "

    print("\ntime finish",i," second")
```

this is the result in console:

```
Enter s char s
Enter g char g
Enter f char f
f==>the waited result but the program block like the first question
```

without putting the result in `t` `variable` i find in result the `f char` but when i put the result in `t variable` the console show me this number `(15)` why this number ? why not `(102)` the ASCII code of `f char` 
this is the result in console:

```
Enter s char s
Enter g char g
Enter f char 15 ==> why this number ?
s
Enter f char 
time almost finish: 5
Enter f char 
('\ntime finish', 10, ' second')
```

i hope find some help thanks